Using SDL2 with the DRM of the Linux kernel
I'm currently writing a minimal Linux distro for personal use with the Linux kernel and BusyBox. I use QEMU for debugging and no fancy build system like CMake, just basic shell scripts.
When the I start the VM, system directories (such as /dev) are mounted and it enters a minimal terminal that I wrote myself for the debugging process. It can run a few commands and also run binaries located in the /bin directory of BusyBox filesystem.
Every program I wrote, was statically linked and didn't use libc functions like malloc or atoi because I did not find a way to include the libraries in the distro. So, I wrote the functions myself.
I wanted the distro to be graphical and fullscreen so I started writing a program using the linux framebuffer /dev/fb0 that displays a few colors into screen and exit. The program work as expected but when doing some research I found out that the framebuffer is old and not recommended.
So, when digging up more, I found that a better approach would be to use the linux DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) along with the KMS (Kernel Mode Setting).
When following a bunch of websites and tutorials (I never wrote an linux distro before), I managed to write a program with a gray background and a blue cursor. The only issue... it was SLOW! If I move the cursor a bit too fast, it can't follow along like I would expect.
And I found DRM a bit too complicated for me, so I wanted to try using SDL2 instead as I found it supports DRM&KMS. But I didn't manage to find any useful article talking about it.
So, I was wondering if it was possible to create a graphical program with SDL2 and the Linux DRM, and if it was possible to not use display servers such as X11 or Wayland?

Works for me on a Raspberry Pi 3 & a regular desktop system.

@genpfault not working for me unfortunately. I tried fixing it but still stuck. It's asking me to have a few kms shared libraries for cirrus, radeon, etc. But when I put the .so files in the corresponding directory (/usr/lib/dri) it's still asking for it

I came across the same issue as you and discovered that Nintendo released their OSS source code for their SNES Classic on their website. Their SDL fork contains direct support for Linux DRM.
